# asp.net mvc ViewModel result wont appear

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i have this table

```
[Table("Quiz")]
public class Quiz
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int QuizId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Submitby { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Score> Scores { get; set; }
}
```

and this

```
[Table("Score")]
public class Score
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ScoreId { get; set; }
    public int QuizId { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public virtual Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
}
```

so i have this viewmodel

```
public class ScoreQuizViewModel
{
    public Score Score { get; set; }
    public Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
}
```

and make this controller

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Quiz quiz = db.Quizs.Find(id);
        if (quiz == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(new ScoreQuizViewModel());
    }
```

the problem is, theres nothing shown on my view
im using

> @model SeedSimple.Models.ScoreQuizViewModel

and accessing with

> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Quiz.Content)

i can see the result if im not using viewmodel.
how i can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're never filling in your `ScoreQuizViewModel` your code should look like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    Quiz quiz = db.Quizs.Find(id);
    if (quiz == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(new ScoreQuizViewModel { Quiz = quiz });
}
```